# SPFx, should I have two Dev environments for SharePoint on-prem 2019 and SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, 2019, development-enviroment

1. As I understand  SharePoint 2019 on-prem supports older version of SPFx and dependencies. So I need to hold two dev environments if I want to make webparts/extensions for both on-prem and online SharePoint editions?
2. Can You please send me working versions for SharePoint 2019. Or maybe somewhere is step-by-step how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [Simultaneously run multiple versions of the SPFx Yeoman generator with npx](https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/simultaneously-run-multiple-versions-of.html)?

You can use 2 versions on same machine and create 2 different projects for 2019 and Online.

It is recommended to create different Dev environments.

Supported SharePoint Framework version for the **SharePoint 2019 is SPFx v1.4.1**.

[SPFx With SharePoint 2019](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/spfx-with-sharepoint-2019/) might help you in case of SharePoint 2019.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You much @harshal gite!

Comment: @GennadyG, current version of Yeoman generator (`yo @microsoft/sharepoint`) allows to create solution targeted for both SP 2019 on-prem and SP Online. SPFx version in such solution is 1.4.1.

Comment: @23W thank You! Remeber I had problems when I played with this.. NVM allowed to install two separate versions of NodeJs but I stucked with something else.. Thank You for response!